# delete a row based on id

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to delete a row based on its ID

HTML:

```
<form action=""  method="post">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value=" delete "/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
        $u = $_REQUEST['edit']; // contains the ID of row to be deleted

        if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
            $db->exec("DELETE FROM infos WHERE id = '$u'");
        }
```

Nothing happens when the delete button is pressed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements as described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: You have no input with `name="edit"` in the form.

Comment: where is edit element?

Comment: @Barmar what will that do?

Answer (score 3):

You need an `edit` input whose value is the ID your want to delete.

```
<form action=""  method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="edit" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value=" delete "/>
</form>
```

Replace `$id` with the actual variable you use in the script that creates the form.

Comment: Did you replace `$id` with the actual variable from your script?

Comment: what if i wanted to redirect to another page when the delete button is clicked also? When I try to change action it goes to that page but noting gets deleted

Comment: The script that processes the form should send an HTTP redirect to the new page, using `header("Location: newURL")`

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action=""  method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="edit" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value=" delete "/>
</form>
```

After that try this

```
$u = $_REQUEST['edit']; // contains the ID of row to be deleted
if($u){
   $db->exec("DELETE FROM infos WHERE id = '$u'");
}
```

Apparently when you are submitting only you posting data to php file.So you can check like this is enough.you told delete not happening so that i am posting this answer

Comment: what if i wanted to redirect to another page when the delete button is clicked also? When I try to change action to a page, it goes to that page but noting gets deleted

Comment: check edit element keeps value or not by change type='hidden1'..if not it wont be delete

Comment: so theres no way I can delete and direct to another page?